# MySQL Query Where NOT

Tags: mysql, sql

How would I create a MySQL query like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM users WHERE ip NOT '66.249.73.202' ORDER BY lastlogin DESC
```

Comment: In the future, please try to do *some* kind of research before posting a question. MySQL has a [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal) that answers these kinds of basic questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE ip != '66.249.73.202' ORDER BY lastlogin DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

MySQL 101:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE ip != '66.249.73.202' ORDER BY lastlogin DESC
```